# How to Invert a Multivariate Interpolating Function?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, inverse

I used NSolve on a partial differential equation with boundary conditions to get a numerical solution that Mathematica says is of the form InterpolatingFunction. I then defined a function f(x,y) which evaluates this solution for a given (x,y). I want to be able to retrieve all of the values of (x,y) such that f(x,y) = C for a given constant C, and then pick the (x,y) in this set that maximizes a different (non-interpolative) function g(x,y). Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Perhaps something like `Maximize[{g[x,y], f[x,y]==C}, {x,y}]`?  Or `NMaximize` etc.  Hard to tell without some code to play with.

Comment: Do you mean you used `NDSolve` (not `NSolve`)?  For finding zeros of interpolating functions, see [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42310/12).

Comment: Were this question clarified with even a minimal example, it would become clear that it is not a duplicate of the linked Q&A. (For instance, I don't think this problem can be solved with `WhenEvent`.)