# intersection between two curves in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have a `ListLinePlot` of some datas and a plot of a constant function. How can I find the intersection point?

My `data` are:

```
data = {{0.2*10^4, 0.57}, {0.6*10^3, 0.56}, {0.2*10^3, 0.55}, {0.6*10^2, 0.53}, 
        {0.2*10^2, 0.49}, {6, 0.44}, {2, 0.38}, {0.6, 0.33}, {0.2, 0.23}};
```

and I would like to find the intersection with `y = 0.29`.

Comment: Let's see a concrete example?

Comment: I have these datas:

Comment: {{0.2*10^4, 0.57}, {0.6*10^3, 0.56}, {0.2*10^3, 0.55}, {0.6*10^2, 
  0.53}, {0.2*10^2, 0.49}, {6, 0.44}, {2, 0.38}, {0.6, 0.33}, {0.2, 
  0.23}} and i vahe done the ListLinePlot. But i have  yo intersecate this plot with y=0.29. How can i find the solution?

Comment: NSolve[(0.29 - 0.23)/(x - 0.2) == (0.33 - 0.23)/(0.6 - 0.2), x]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42324/1356) function:

```
data = {{0.2*10^4, 0.57}, {0.6*10^3, 0.56}, {0.2*10^3, 0.55}, {0.6*10^2, 0.53}, 
        {0.2*10^2, 0.49}, {6, 0.44}, {2, 0.38}, {0.6, 0.33}, {0.2, 0.23}};
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
y[x_] := 0.29
x0 = First[x /. FindRoot[f[x] - y[x], {x, #[[1, 1]], #[[2, 1]]}] & /@ 
       Select[Partition[Sort@Last@Last@Reap[Plot[f[x] - y[x], {x, 0.2, 2000}, 
           EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x] - y[x]}]]], 2, 1], #[[2, 2]] #[[1, 2]] <= 0 &]];
Plot[{f[x], y[x]}, {x, 0.2, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@.02, Point@{#, y@#} &@x0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the coordinates of the point are:

```
{#, y@#} &@x0
```

> ```
> {0.44, 0.29}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I might sound terribly pedantic here, but the answer is simply: Not at all.

The problem is that you have a finite set of data points, none of which has a y-value of 0.29. So there is no 'intersection' between a constant line and a number of points.

The other two answers above gave you a solution on how to find the intersection between the horizontal line and a *suitably interpolated data set* - in both cases linear interpolation has been assumed. That works, of course, but is the answer to your question only under very restricted circumstances (in case you wonder `ListLinePlot` has the option `InterpolationOrder`).

So if this is a real-world problem, you would have to specify what sort of function is used to either interpolate or fit your data set and then use `FindRoot` or 'NSolve' to obtain a numerical approximation.