# Find Intersection of Two Interpolation Functions

Tags: equation-solving, interpolation

How can I find the intersection between two interpolation functions?

```
data1 = Table[10*x, {x, 0, 10, 1}]
data2 = Table[-10*x, {x, -10, 2, 1}]

intdata1 = Interpolation[data1];
intdata2 = Interpolation[data2];

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2}]

Solve[intdata1[x] == intdata2[x], x]
```

This doesn't work, with an error of

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available
>   to Solve.

Comment: Related: [(23609)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23609), [(35107)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35107), [(42304)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42304)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In[9]:= x/.FindRoot[intdata1[x]==intdata2[x],{x,3}]
Out[9]= 6.
```